# MPMoviePlayerController - Auto-Resume on headphone plugged in

Tags: objective-c, audio, mpmovieplayercontroller

Having a slight problem with MPMoviePlayerController. I am playing a movie and if the user unpluggs the headphones from the audio-jack, it pauses the movie (a standard iOS feature).

However, When the user plugs the headphones back into the jack. The movie doesnt auto resume.

Is there somthing I am missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MPMoviePlayerController - automatically paused

listen to kAudioSessionProperty_AudioRouteChange property

```
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>

void callbackHeadphone_func ( void *inClientData, AudioSessionPropertyID inID, UInt32 inDataSize, const void *inData ) {
        if ( inID == kAudioSessionProperty_AudioRouteChange ) {

        }
    }


    - (void) isHeadsetPluggedIn {

        UInt32 routeSize = sizeof (CFStringRef); CFStringRef route;

        AudioSessionGetProperty (kAudioSessionProperty_AudioRoute, &routeSize, &route);

        AudioSessionAddPropertyListener (kAudioSessionProperty_AudioRouteChange, callbackHeadphone_func, self);
        /* Known values of route:
         "Headset"
         "Headphone"
         "Speaker"
         "SpeakerAndMicrophone"
         "HeadphonesAndMicrophone"
         "HeadsetInOut"
         "ReceiverAndMicrophone"
         "Lineout" */

        NSString* routeStr = (NSString*)route;
        NSLog(@"%@",routeStr);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

When will you return the headphones into the jack, your video or music does not continue playing. This feature of iOS.

You need to programmatically determine when the user connected the headphones, and then programmatically to continue playing.
To determine the status of headphones, I use the function "propListener" of the sample aurioTouch (from Apple).
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/aurioTouch/aurioTouch.zip